# iOS Leaderboards Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center

In my iOS app I created two leaderboards in Game Center. I have it all set up. I am just wondering if I can make it so when you tap a button it opens both leaderboards. I have the below code but don't know how to make it open both.

```
leaderboardController.category = self.currentLeaderBoard;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably won't be able to - look at the Game Center Leaderboard UI. **Game Center is not optimized for this, and Apple won't allow it if it doesn't look good**.